# Using iMac as a machine to create a Private Cloud (Eucalyptus)

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-10.04, eucalyptus

I am trying to use two iMac 2011 core i5 to create a private cloud as they are only 64bit machines that I have now. I planed to use one for CLC and another one for Node controller. I tried to installed Eucalyptus cloud from 
Ubuntu 10.04 server CDinstaller. I can installed it on Paralle but fail on the real machine as every time because I cannot pass Network detection step as it shows Ubuntu cannot contact DHCP server. But these steps can be done on Paralle and VM. And has no problem when I installed Ubuntu 12.04 server on both real machine and VM. So I wonder if iMac is suitable to use as a Machune for UEC?

And another question is when I tried to install Node controller on VM / Paralle during the steps it shows "The hardware doesn't support virtualization, Eucalyptus running on this hardware will be unaccelerated". How should I do for these problems? And what is the machine that support virtualization (let says if I can use iMac for this project, what I have to adapt to. Or any command lines to solve the problems.)

Thank you.

==
My iMac specs
http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-2.7-21-inch-aluminum-mid-2011-thunderbolt-specs.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can run Eucalyptus on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the question is about installing on the physical box - not be confused with trying to install it on the Mac OSX environment. Given that the physical device will have an x68 based chip I don't see a reason why this wouldn't be possible.

Is the target iMac physically connected to the network? I ask because on my test laptop (ThinkPad) I've noticed that installing Euca using just the wireless NIC won't work. Or is more difficult than I wanted to deal with ;-)

And I'd bet that the virtualized methods you tried (i.e. Parallells) got further because it faked a hardwired NIC AND the your underlying environment was already properly configured to see the DHCP server.this

Answer (score 0):

As Vasya said, Eucalyptus is not designed to run on Mac. Using cloud in a box it may be possible, but you will need a lot of digging into Mac to set up the network and the nested virutalization needed to pull that off.